# Circled references within code lstlisting

Tags: code, annotations, lstdefinestyle

So I just want to create some circled numbers within my code `lstlisting`, which I could easily reference within a nearby description text.

```
This is my description text and I want to refer to [1] in \ref{lst:code}:

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={some code here},label={lst:code}]
public int do_something(param 1) {
  int a;
  int b; [1]
  return a+b;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

It should finally look something like this within in the listing and the description:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two parts to the answer:

- First, you need a way to escape inside the `listings` environment to LaTex, to execute a LaTeX reference command. Choose delimiters that escape the LaTeX commands that are not used in your code. Since your example seems to in `C`, I would suggest `\*!` and `!*\` as escape characters. Setup with:

  ```
  \lstset{escapeinside={/*!}{!*/}}
  ```
- Second, you can define an own counter and define references to it using circled symbols like in your example picture. Here, I use from the `pifonts` package the symbols `\ding{182}` to `\ding{191}`. I define then a command that (1) increases the counter, (2) sets a reference, and (3) prints the encircled number:

  ```
      \newcommand{\annotation}[1]{\refstepcounter{lstannotation}\label{#1}\thelstannotation}
  ```

  You can then use `\annotation{mylabel}` to create a reference with the label `mylabel`.

Combining both gives a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapeinside={/*!}{!*/}}

\newcounter{lstannotation}
\setcounter{lstannotation}{0}
\renewcommand{\thelstannotation}{\ding{\number\numexpr181+\arabic{lstannotation}}}
\newcommand{\annotation}[1]{\refstepcounter{lstannotation}\label{#1}\thelstannotation}

\begin{document}

This is my description text and I want to refer to \ref{lst:annotation1} and \ref{lst:annotation2} in \ref{lst:code}:

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={some code here},label={lst:code}]
public int do_something(param 1) {
  int a;
  int b; /*!\annotation{lst:annotation1}!*/
  return a+b;
} /*!\annotation{lst:annotation2}!*/
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So I have one little issue with this solution. As I only did only a short POC during the week, I now have the following issue: \ref{lst:annotation2} won't be incremented. So it's displaying only two (1) within in the paragraph for both references \ref{lst:annotation1} and \ref{lst:annotation2} . Do you have any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Right, I didn't test to reference the second annotation. I updated the answer: the solution is essentially to replace `\value` with `\arabic`.